# Unhandled IOErrorEvent in SWF file called by Flex4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4

HI,
I am getting an issue, that might be simple to solve it, but I`m stuck in it, so....

here is my code:

```
<mx:SWFLoader source="@Embed('assets/games/memory.swf')" includeIn="memory" trustContent="true"/>
```

I am loading a swf file, which I did, but the think is, in this swf file I am doing URL request to get an image file, when I open the swf it works fine, but when I loaded using the code above, I`m getting  a error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

everything loads fine, just the image which I am getting externally it`s not loading!

Someone know how to solve that?

thanks!

EDIT:

if I run as debug mode, I got this message in console:

```
[SWF] Machine.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/1 - 277,632 bytes after decompression
SharedObjectExample() loaded
SharedObject loaded...

loaded value: undefined
```

EDIT2:
Interesting think, I got working using a [BulkLoader](https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader/), and the interesting think is, when I use the BulkLoader and running in debug mode, I got:

```
[SWF] assets/games/memory.swf - 277,632 bytes after decompression
SharedObjectExample() loaded
SharedObject loaded...

loaded value: undefined
```

It might be PATH issue, the question is:
When I load using SWFLoader, does it load in a different context path?

Comment: Is the URL being loaded by the memory.swf file a relative path, if so it's likely the swf that contains memory.swf just doesn't have the same base directory and so the relative path doesn't resolve correctly, if you use firefox install firebug and watch the traffic to see what URL it's requesting from to determine how to change the relative path if need be, otherwise add a listener for the FaultEvent.FAULT and drop a breakpoint in there to see if the fault gives you any more info.  (alternative to firebug get Charles web debugging proxy, free trial great program well worth 50 bucks)

Comment: I`m doing a air app, so cannot use firefox plugins! try to add FaultEvent.FAULT, but it`s not getting there!

Comment: could you please post the URL of the image that is loaded into `memory.swf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, the trick is, if I load the swf files as 'Embed' all the relative path(inside the swf) will be my main app(mais swf), so I was getting this trace:

```
[SWF] Machine.swf/[[DYNAMIC]]/1 - 277,632 bytes after decompression
```

If I want to use realtive paths inside my 'child' swf, I cannot load as 'Embed'!

so, to solve that I just change my code to:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="loader" source="assets/games/memory.swf" includeIn="memory"/>
```

EDIT:

I posted a thread in my blog explain it as well: http://arthurnn.com/blog/2011/02/03/trick-using-swfloader-to-load-a-swf-file/